# Good Practice of using ThreadLocal in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, thread-local

I have a question regarding to how I should use `ThreadLocal`.

**Context and Situation**

There are several singleton objects that use `ThreadLocal` to create one copy per thread. This singleton object has a function `foo()`.

```
public class SingletonA {
    protected static ThreadLocal<SingletonA> singleton = new ThreadLocal<SingletonA>() {
        @Override
        protected SingletonA initialValue() {
            return new SingletonA();
        }
    };

    private SingletonA() { ... }
    public static SingletonA getInstance() { return singleton.get(); }
    public static void remove() { singleton.remove(); }
    public static void foo() { ... }
}
```

... There are SingletonB, SingletonC, and so forth.

There is a singleton repository that caches the `ThreadLocal` singletons above. This class is also a `ThreadLocal` singleton -

```
public class SingletonRepo {
        protected static ThreadLocal<SingletonRepo> singleton = new ThreadLocal<SingletonRepo>() {
        @Override
        protected SingletonRepo initialValue() {
            return new SingletonRepo();
        }
    };

    private SingletonRepo() { ... }
    public static SingletonRepo getInstance() { return singleton.get(); }
    public static void remove() { singleton.remove(); }

    public SingletonA singletonA;
    // same thing for singletonB, singletonC, ...

   public static init() {
        // Caching the ThreadLocal singleton
        singletonA = SingletonA.getInstance();
        // Same thing for singletonB, singletonC ...
   }
}
```

This is currently how I access the `ThreadLocal` singletons through `SingletonRepo`

```
public class App {
    public SingletonRepo singletonRepo;
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        singletonRepo = SingletonRepo.getInstance();
        singletonRepo.init();

        singletonRepo.singletonA.helperFunction();
    }
}
```

**Question**

As you have seen in the context above, in order to access the `ThreadLocal` singletons, I first cached them in the `SingletonRepo`. When I need to use the `ThreadLocal` singleton, I get it from the cache reference. I have the following questions -

1. Is it a bad practice to access the `ThreadLocal` singleton through a cache copy?
2. Is it a better practice to always access the `ThreadLocal` singleton through `SingletonA.getInstance()` (Calling `get()` for the Singleton object)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thread local cached copy is fine as it is simpler and more efficient.  A cached copy where you are not sure it is thread local could be a problem.

A singleton by definition means there can only be one.  I wouldn't what you have as a singleton and you have one per thread.

I would init() your thread local object in it's constructor.

BTW Your ThreadLocal should be `private static final` I suspect.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Peter! I understand that whenever I use a singleton object, there should only be one object. However, the system was designed this way and I needed concurrency support for these objects, so this is the best solution I can have now without significantly changing the system. Also, the reason why I'm asking this question is that I seem to have race conditions when I use the solution as mentioned in 1, but it is resolved when I use the solution as mentioned in 2. Any clue why?

Comment: @thinket I don't have a problem with having thread local objects but calling an object a "singleton" when it is not a singleton is confusing.

Comment: @thinket I don't see how the second block of code really works as there is no such method `SingletonA.getInstance()`.  The first example is simpler and I would expect it to have less problems.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not quite clear what you want to achieve. The performance aspects of a `ThreadLocal` lookup are negligible so “caching” a value doesn’t make much sense, especially as you still have to look up the cache instance.

It was more useful, if the types `SingletonA`, `SingletonB`, `SingletonC`, etc. did not have a `ThreadLocal` so the `SingletonRepo` was the sole instance maintained via `ThreadLocal` while the other instances are maintained by `SingletonRepo` and thus implicitly thread-local. However, in order to implement it this way, the constructors of `SingletonA`, `SingletonB`, `SingletonC`, etc. have to be accessible by `SingletonRepo`.

What strikes me, given the way you have implemented it currently, is that there is a `remove` method on the singleton classes as well as on the repo class which therefore allows inconsistencies. E.g., I can call `SingletonRepo.getInstance().init()` followed by `SingletonA.remove()` and et voilà you have created the situation for your current thread where `SingletonRepo.getInstance().singletonA` contains a reference to an instance while `SingletonA.singleton` doesn’t hold a value and will create a new instance on the next invocation of `getInstance()` so that two different instances exist at the same time for the same thread.